# How to select a polygon and use it as a clipping mask for other layers in Folium?

Tags: python, geopandas, folium

I have a geoJSON file of local authorities and several other layers shown on the same Folium map. I want the user to select a polygon (one of the local authorities) and then turn on other layers. I want these layers to be clipped to a polygon that user selected.

[Snapshot of the map.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vqZQi.jpg)

I would assume geopandas would do the clipping, but I can't get my head around on selecting a polygon and how to perform analysis on it. Is this even possible with Folium, or would this need to be done in combination with javascript?

I am not expecting the exact code example, but if someone could point me in the right direction that would be appreciated already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think **ipyleaflet** will help in solving your problem.

Please check it's [GitHub](https://github.com/jupyter-widgets/ipyleaflet) repo and [documentation](https://ipyleaflet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Comment: You are probably right, I've done some research and found out that ipyleaflet is much more appropriate for interactive mapping than Folium. Will give it a go.